# C++ Inheritance and Initialisation order

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am studying for my final exam. I stumbled upon this question from previous years and I can't seem to fully understand whats happening.
*Given this code, determine the output*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A {
    A(int a): _a(a) {cout << "A::A, a=" << _a << endl;} 
    ~A() { cout << "A::~" << endl; }
    int _a;
};

struct B: public A
{
    B(int b):A(b) { cout << "B::B" << endl; }
    ~B() { cout << "B::~" << endl; } 
};

struct C: public B
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C(int a=10, int b=20):a(a), b(a*b), B(b) {} 
    ~C() { cout << "C::~" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    C allTogetherNow;
    return 0; 
}
```

I tried to compile the code and I was given a warning:

> warning: field 'b' will be initialized after base 'B'
>         [-Wreorder] C(int a=10, int b=20):a(a), b(a*b), B(b) {} ~C() { cout << "C::~" << endl; }
>                               ^ 1 warning generated.

and the following output:

```
A::A, a=20
B::B
A::A, a=10
A::A, a=200
B::B
C::~
B::~
A::~
A::~
B::~
A::~
```

The destruction order is kind of clear (last constructed - first destructed), but I can't seem to get ahold of the construction order/pattern.. What am I missing? A clarification of the *Warning* I received would be extra helpful. Also, if you could refer me to extra reading material on this particular subject.

Thank you.

Comment: The order in which things are initialized is NOT based on the order in which they appear in the initialization list. That's what the warning is telling you. If you reorder the initialization list to the actual construction order, the warning is fixed.

Comment: Base classes are initialized in the order they are specified in the base-specifier list. That means the base class `B` is constructed first despite it appearing last in the initializer list.

Comment: Given the output, what exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 5):

The initialization order is precisely defined in the standard:

> **12.6.2./10:**  In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor
>   of the most derived class (1.8), **virtual base classes** are
>   initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right
>   traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where
>   “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the
>   derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, **direct base classes** are
>   initialized in declaration order as they appear in the
>   base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, **non-static data members** are initialized in the order they
>   were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order
>   of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the compound-statement of the
>   constructor body is executed.

So when you intialize C,  its base class is first initialised, i.e. `B` with default 20 which itself requires `A` to be initialised first with 20. Only then is initialisation of `B` completed.

Then, `A` and `B` being intialized, the members of `C` are initalized, starting first with `a` with the default parameter 10, then with `b(200)`.  As `b` is a `B`, it will first require the initializeation of its own base `A`. Then initialisation of of `b` can be completed.  And finally the initialisation of `C` is completed.

By the way, it's not part of the question but remember  for your exam:

> **12.4/7:** Bases and members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their constructor.

***Note about the warning:***

*My compiler doesn't generate this warning. There is no reason for it, as the mem-initilizer `B(b)` clearly uses the parameter `b` of your consturctor.  It's only an hypotheses, but I suspect your compiler raise a false positive because `b` is also the name of a member (which would indeed not be initialised when calling the base).  If I'm right, the following change should not raise a warning anymore:*

```
 C(int a=10, int bbb=20):a(a), b(a*bbb), B(bbb) { cout << "C::C" << endl;}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
C(int a=10, int b=20):a(a), b(a*b), B(b) {}
```

Should be:

```
C(int a=10, int b=20): B(b), a(a), b(a*b) {}
```

In C++, the initialization order is fixed. For your type `C`, it will always be:

1. Base Class `B`
2. Member variable `A a;`
3. Member variable `B b;`

In your initializer list you ordered it differently. And so your compiler warned you in case you expected the initializer list's order to matter.

Comment: So the compiler basically auto-fixed that for me. Is this a rule of thumb to follow? Even if the code is not correctly written? Always init base class before members?

Comment: @Airwavezx Base classes are ALWAYS initialized before members. Always.